# How to get element's index for PandasArray object

Tags: python, pandas

If I have this kind of code `a=pd.array(['a', 'b'], dtype=str)`. How can I get index of element 'a'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated version,

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.array(['a', 'b'], dtype=str)
series = pd.Series(a)

index = series[series == 'a'].index[0]
print(index)
```

Comment: I got this error, 'PandasArray' object has no attribute 'get_indexer'

Comment: See the updated code. With updated method there is no need of the indexer method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pandas.Series to get it done.
If you need you can create a new variable being the Array converted to a Series just to get the index. Then just use the Array for all the things you need.
`data = pd.Series(a)`

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample Series
data = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print(data)

# Get the index of an element
element = 'e'
index = data[data == element].index[0]
print(index)
```

The output of the last print is 4

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
pd.Index(a).get_loc('a')
```